# Were the 5 men indicted for murder?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bride-wore-black

I recently saw, 30+ years after my first viewing, the 1968 Truffaut classic *La mariée était en noir*, starring Jeanne Moreau as the avenging bride Julie Kohler. There's something in the plot that I don't get.

Were the five men that Julie was chasing indicted for killer her husband?  If not, how did Julie track them?

Comment: Does this answer satisfy you? If not, what sort of information would you like to see?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to answer this is that Julie tracked them because the script told her where they would be!

I know it's not a great answer, but there isn't a very logical explanation as to how she could have done it.

Some people over at the [IMDB forums](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061955/board/thread/22716642) have had a discussion about this same issue. The nearest thing to any sort of explanation was offered by one of the posters:

> When she locked one of the men in the closet, he told her how they
>   always used that room to play poker in. She would have been told
>   (or figured out) the projectory of the shot, she would have discovered
>   it came from that building and just bribe the tenants into finding out
>   who used that room even though the men never met there again. Money
>   opens doors as surely as doorknobs

I fully admit this is a little weak and requires a massive stretch, but she is intelligent and did have some five and a half years to plan the murders.

Having said that, I stick with my first comment. I think it largely happened because it made the script work - nothing more than that.

As to whether the men were indicted - there appears to be no evidence anywhere that they were.